# Como simplificar o processo de verificar um determinado valor?

Tags: php, revisão-de-código

Por exemplo, quando eu preciso verificar alguns determinados valores, eu crio um "*método*", semelhante a esse:

```
public function verificaString($campo)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$campo]) && (!empty($_POST[$campo]) && (is_string($_POST[$campo])))):
        (string)$var = filter_var(trim($_POST[$campo]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        return $var;
    else:
        $var = 'Indisponível';
        return $var;
    endif;
}
```

Agora pensando nessa parte mais especificamente:

> `if (isset($_POST[$campo]) && (!empty($_POST[$campo])`

**Não existe uma maneira de simplificar esse processo?**

Toda vez que eu preciso verificar se uma variável está setada e ela tiver um valor diferente de nulo, eu tenho que fazer exatamente isso? Não tem como simplificar esse procedimento?

Answer (score 2):

Utilizar `isset` e utilizar `!empty` (no seu caso) é redundante, pois `empty` faz exatamente o contrário do `isset` (basicamente ele é `!isset($var);`) com a adição do comando de negação da variável. Ou seja:

```
empty($var); // true
```

é igual a:

```
!isset($var) || !$var; // true
```

O resultado de `empty` será o mesmo que `!isset` e negação (acima demonstrada). Ou seja, você pode adicionar na sua condição que seja apenas `!empty`.

Já no seu método, você pode utilizar *early returns* e remover o `if`/`else` do seu método o que deixará ele com uma melhor leitura e uma menor complexidade ciclomática:

```
public function verificaString($campo)
{
    if (empty($_POST[$campo]) || !is_string($_POST[$campo]))
    {
        return 'Indisponível';
    }

    return filter_var(trim($_POST[$campo]), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
```

Perceba a inversão da instrução `if` que está validando se o valor, na superglobal $_POST, é vazia ou diferente de string. Caso for verdadeiro, retorna que é indisponível.

O else, não se faz mais necessário, pois, o return interrompe a execução do código. Caso o código não cair no if, pode ser realizado a sanitização da string.

Agora, saber se o método é útil ou não (simplificar a existência do método) é algo que não posso afirmar com tão pouco trechos de código.

Comment: Por favor, reveja o seu último código, parece que o retorno da função `is_string` está sendo passado como parâmetro de `empty` junto com o valor de `$_POST`.

Comment: O isset é diferente do empty. O empty verifica se não existe e não tem valor. O isset verifica se existe.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss corrigdo, valeu pela informação

Comment: @LucasCarvalho leia novamente o que eu escrevi, o empty é o contrário do isset + a negação da variável. Veja o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty ou o próprio manual

Comment: O [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) verifica se uma variável está/foi **setada e não é nula**. Já o [empty()](http://php.net/empty) verifica se ela **está vazia**.

Comment: @lucascarvalho o `empty` é um construtor de linguagem e faz exatamente o que foi dito na resposta, como é citado também na documentação. Portanto é possível omitir o `isset` se utilizado o `empty`, sim.

Comment: @UzumakiArtanis Havia faltado uma negação no `empty`, mas a definição escrita ainda está correta. Veja os comentários acima.

Comment: Sim, está certo :) Só estou dizendo que não é a mesma coisa. Podem fazer as mesmas coisas, mas não são as mesmas coisas.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Em nenhum momento foi dito que são a mesma coisa. Apenas que estão redundantes no código.

Comment: É exatamente como você disse @GabrielHeming. O empty com isset da maneira usada é uma redundância. Basta utilizar o empty que já é suficiente.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se é exatamente isso que você procura mas vou arriscar uma maneira mais limpa e linda de verificar se suas variáveis via post estão sendo passadas:

Ex:

```
$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Valor da requisitada variável em caso de sucesso, **FALSE** se o filtro falhar, ou **NULL** se o parâmetro variable_name é um variável não definida. Se a flag **FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE** é usada, ela retorna **FALSE** se a variável não é definida e **NULL** se o filtro falhar.

Para mais informações segue o [manual do php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), abraços e bons estudos garoto!!!

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando o [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php):

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, $campo, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
```

Há uma [lista de constantes pré-definidas](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php) para os filtros.

Você pode então simplicar um pouco e reduzir a tua função junto do [`operador ternário`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
public function verificaString($campo)
{
    return trim(filter_input(INPUT_POST, $campo, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) ?:  'Indisponível';
}
```